# Comparison not working on first call

Tags: jquery, image, comparison, conditional-statements, src

**Purpose:** vote.php limits voting on each post to one per IP. The jQuery checks the old vote value compared to the new vote value. If the vote increases, a picture is changed. If the vote decreases, a picture is changed. If the vote does not change, the picture remains default.

**Problem:** Script still changes the image on first run even though the values are equal(checked with window.alert). All executions after first run work as intended.

**Problematic Code:**

```
if (window.f != voteTotal.text()) {
//alert place here. voteTotal.text() && window.f are equal
if (votetype == "up") {

$('.bg').attr('src', 'tear.gif');
window.t=setTimeout('changeBack()', 3000);
}

else if (votetype =="down") {
$('.bg').attr('src', 'happy.gif');
window.t=setTimeout('changeBack()', 3000);
}
else {
changeBack();
}
}
else if(window.f == voteTotal.text()){
changeBack();
}
else {
changeBack();
}
```

var f is declared outside of the function and given value as soon as the function is called by the user clicking on a vote option.

**Full code:**

```
var t;
var f;

function vote(vote_id, votetype) {
window.f = $('#vote' + vote_id).text();
$.post('vote.php', {id: vote_id, type: votetype },
function(output) {
$('#vote' + vote_id).html(output).show();
colorChange(vote_id, votetype);    
});    
}



function colorChange(vote_id, votetype) {
var voteTotal = $('#vote' + vote_id);



if (window.f != voteTotal.text()) {

if (votetype == "up") {

$('.bg').attr('src', 'tear.gif');
window.t=setTimeout('changeBack()', 3000);
}

else if (votetype =="down") {
$('.bg').attr('src', 'happy.gif');
window.t=setTimeout('changeBack()', 3000);
}
else {changeBack();}
}
else if(window.f == voteTotal.text()){
changeBack();
}
else {
changeBack();
}

 }



function changeBack() {
$('.bg').attr('src', 'bg.gif');

}
```

So, where have I gone wrong?

---

This code is included in my header.html inside of the head tags. What you see is the .js file. This is all there is.

```
if (window.f == voteTotal.text()) {window.alert('They are equal');}
else { window.alert('They are not equal: ' + voteTotal.text() + ' ' +window.f); }
```

[image: I am completely confused]

It works, just not the first time through.

[image: Second time clicking on the same div]

Comment: Is your JavaScript located before your closing body tag? Are you running your JS inside jQuery's ready()?

Comment: Added a second edit. I'm running the JS inside of the head. I used no ready() and the happy.gif and tear.gif are not cached.

Comment: Can you move it to the bottom of the page?

Comment: Just tried. It's doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting your total votes from an html element, try trimming it first.
Since it only does this on the first run, there may be something up with the markup for that particular element in the html itself, in which I'd go and change it there. Id personally get the vote count from the server.

I've also trimmed some stuff off the colorchange function.

```
function vote(vote_id, votetype) {
  window.f = $.trim($('#vote' + vote_id).text());
  $.post('vote.php', {id: vote_id, type: votetype },
  function(output) {
        $('#vote' + vote_id).html(output).show();
  colorChange(vote_id, votetype);    
  });    
 }

function colorChange(vote_id, votetype) {
var voteTotal = $('#vote' + vote_id);

if (window.f != $.trim(voteTotal.text())) {        
//alert place here. voteTotal.text() && window.f are equal
    if (votetype == "up") {

       $('.bg').attr('src', 'tear.gif');
       window.t=setTimeout('changeBack()', 3000);
    }

    else if (votetype =="down") {
        $('.bg').attr('src', 'happy.gif');
        window.t=setTimeout('changeBack()', 3000);
    }


}else {

    changeBack();

}//if
}//changeColor
```

Comment: When I trim() it does not change the image in either case. The div is named Vote + their ID from the table as set by vote.php. The original works as expected after the first execution on each ID. I have no idea why it does not work on the first execution.